# PHP : Execute sql queries in background

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, background-process

I'm using PHP (Yii framework) and Postgresql for the db. Basically a [wappstack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp). I just mentioned them if ever they are a concern for this problem.

Anyway, what i'm trying to achieve is I have a submit action:

```
public function actionSubmitData($id){


    //Execute Sql queries here

$this->render('view',array(
                //some data
            ));
}
```

The problem is that I will be **processing a large amount of data;** About 50,000 records will be processed in each of 4 tables of roughly 10 columns each table, that is fairly large. The use case is that the user submits, then the sql statements are executed in background, but the view 'view' should already be rendered, not requiring the user to wait for the records to be processed. He/she can check on it later on after the records are processed.

A normal request would execute sql statements first, then render the view. The problem is when the page takes about 3-5 min. The page never loads; and the creation of records is not finished, just a white page appears when the requests are intensive.

In other words, how do I execute sql queries in background? Leaving the user able to browse the application still while the request is **being processed?** And **somewhere in the background**, records are being processed? What is the workaround for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Save the information needed to run the queries, and schedule a job that executes this in the background.

Comment: Try using queues with the Yii framework this will be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: @GolezTrol, can you provide a more specific explanation? proof of concept/ sample code would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest push your queries (jobs) to some messaging system as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Gearman](http://gearman.org/). It will let do your work in parallel. You even be able scale your jobs easily.

- [Gearman: Getting Started](http://gearman.org/getting-started/)
- [Gearman: Examples](http://gearman.org/examples/)
- [Yii German extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gearman/)

Comment: Yep, you need a task queue.

Comment: @Pawka if it's okay.. can you give me a headstart? gearman is especially interesting, but i don't know where to start.. a pseudo code/ proof of concept would really be helpful thanks

Comment: @muffin I've found there are couple Gearman excensions for Yii. This is one of them: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/gearman/ You can find multiple examples in German website too: http://gearman.org/examples/ Simple implementation would be to create console application as worker and run it periodically. On the  frontend side (website) push your task to Gearman server after user submits data.

Comment: i don't even know how to install gearman properly, and add it as a php extension haha.

Answer (score 1):

It must be done using Cron Job.

1. User submits data.
2. System writes all data to some temp file for later use.
3. User is redirected to view page to continue browsing.
4. Cron Job process looks for new file, marks it as `in process` and process it.
5. Cron Job deletes file after processing.

Since Cron Job runs in CLI, you will not get timeout of script.

Comment: I do not think this would be good solution. You'll face more problems definitely. For example deadlocks on your "some temp file"... Also how often run the cron? There are already many tools created to handle such situations. Check queuing/messaging systems.